# Internet does not work well on Ubuntu but does so on Windows

Tags: 12.04, internet-connection

I have  a dual boot system with Windows7 and Ubuntu 12.04 with wired internet connection. It is configured to automatic DHCP. The internet works perfectly well on Windows. But on Ubuntu, the connection sometimes work, sometimes not. On most occasions, internet doesn't work. The indicator does say 'Connection established". I have tried other distros earlier with the same issue. I don't understand why it works well in Windows and not on Ubuntu.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the issue, but you could try disabling IPv6. In NetworkManager, go to `Edit connections...`, then choose your connection and click `Edit...`. On the `IPv6 Settings` tab set `Method` to `Ignore` and re-connect.

Comment: Sorry for being late to respond. 
@ovc, I tried by setting the IPv6 to ignore. It didn't work out.
any other reason for this problem ?